# What is the term for critique, which is itself the kind of behavior being critiqued?

Tags: term

The most basic example:

> Critique of critique is critique

The more complicated example:

> Critique of imposing ethical opinions is imposing ethical opinions.

For the purposes of this example, assume that "critique" amounts to suggesting that critiqued behavior (imposing of ethical opinions) is wrong. When one suggests that someone's behavior is wrong one can not help but appeal to some ethical values (maybe deep inside), and therefore impose one's own ethical opinions.

Is there any term, that may describe this strange sort of critique, that actually beats himself? Except of obvious "recursive critique".

Comment: Thank you for your edit! I suppose it made my question clearer.

Comment: What comes to mind is [self-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-reference), i.e. self-referential critique, and [pragmatic contradictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction#Pragmatic_contradictions).

Comment: "Meta-critique" may be a novel name for it.

Comment: @Conifold, self-reference is pretty good term, because it's actually self-reference, but alas it's too broad.

Comment: @Nick, meta-critique implies that this critique differs from the critique. But in this examples it doesn't.

Comment: Not to be strange on this, but is it not merely 'redundant'? Or some form of circularity?